# Disable pad click

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I keep typing in the wrong place because of the pad getting touched while I am typing causing a click that re-place the cursor in another position. In Windows, I can easily disable that so the pad is only used to move the mouse cursor, but I didn't find similar option in Ubuntu. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't this doing what you want?

[image: mouse preferences window]

This is in System / Preferences / Mouse.

Comment: Hmmmm.... never saw that before!! Why would they put under mouse? In Windows it was an icon in the taskbar, so makes it easy to see. Thanks anyway, I will mark your answer as the accepted answer because it is easier.

Comment: Would the general term "pointing device" be more discoverable than "mouse"?

Answer (score 6):

You can install `touchpad-indicator` to enable/disable the touchpad.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lorenzo-carbonell/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

After installation you can find it under Applications **→** Accessories **→** Touchpad Indicator.
[image: indicator menu]

### Creating shortcut:

You can also create a shortcut for disabling/enabling the touchpad.
[image: touhcpad-indicator box]

**Note:**

- Have a look at **[Automatically Disable TouchPad While Typing](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/ubuntu-automatically-disable-touchpad.html)**.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. One problem though. Say I disabled the touchpad and then left my place and forgot to take the mouse with me. How can I re-enable it (without having the mouse)?

Comment: Oh, the note is even better. Let me try it :-)

Comment: @Promather You can set a shorcut,so that you can enable/disable the touchpad by pressing the combination of keys..See i have updated my answer..

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I should have seen that actually :-)

Answer (score 1):

I installed `touchpad-incidactor` from the `ppa:atareao/atareao` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```