# How can I disable my touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

I would like to find a way to turn my laptop touchpad on and off.  (I generally use a mouse instead.)

I use an HP laptop. Thanks.

Comment: @user13499  What is the model of your laptop?  What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Would the tool in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28175/touchpad-suddenly-stopped-working/28182#28182) answer help? It allows complete control over the touchpad.

Comment: Hp g62. and ubuntu 10.10

Comment: -HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package touchpad-indicator
reborn@reborn-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: @user: I think you need to add a repository first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/21939/disable-pad-click/ .

Answer (score 5):

**Touchpad-Indicator** will allow you to toggle on/off the touchpad, simply, and quickly.

- Open a terminal, and run the
  following:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:atareao/atareao`.

`sudo apt-get update`.

`sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator`.

- You may then launch
  **touchpad-indicator** from **Accessories**.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open `gconf-editor`, navigate to `/desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad` and uncheck "touchpad enabled".

Comment: @user13499: glad to help ;) (btw I have an HP too) - also remember to mark the question as answered by clicking the check box on my answer.

Comment: The key "touchpad enabled" is not available on my system (a Dell Precision)

Comment: @danielkullmann what version of Ubuntu are you using? You may need to open a new question.

Comment: I'm using 11.10

Comment: @danielkullmann I'll have to look up how do it on 11.10 (without a button).

Answer (score 2):

[I've deleted my original answer due to obsolescence (see [How to install Jupiter in Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373484/how-to-install-jupiter-in-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander)), but I've left the links to AU to possibly help future visitors.]

Also see these questions (answers could also be obsolete -- please comment and I'll fix/delete them):

- [Disable pad click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21939/disable-pad-click/)
- [Is there software to manage the laptop's touchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106863/is-there-software-to-manage-the-laptops-touchpad)