# Is there software to manage the laptop's touchpad?

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I was looking for software to manage touchpad and mouse and I found `synaptiks`
but it dosn't work properly !!

For example i want to my laptop's tochpad been disable when i use a mouse but it doesn't happen with this software!!

Do others have this problem ?
is there any other softwares that works well?

Thanks.

Comment: This usually works best with a keyboard shortcut, though this varies my model. Edit your question with the type of laptop, or look in the owner's manual for 'disable touchpad'. It's usually something very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `gpointing-device-settings` :

`sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings`

It has additional options over the stock control panel.  Good luck. Touchpad options in Ubuntu and linux in general appear to the new "WIFI Driver" - it's a bagatelle whether you get proper support for any given model. Modern clickpads (touchpads that incorporate their buttons under a single smooth surface) are particularly poorly supported. Support for certain features comes from the kernel, not the configuration tool itself, so if you can't, say, get two-fingered scrolling working from the stock options, it's unlikely that install `gpointing-device-settings` will make any difference.

Comment: i installed that but when i run it, it returns this error 
`(gpointing-device-settings:3943): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gpointing-device-settings:3943): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gpointing-device-settings:3943): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gpointing-device-settings:3943): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
An X error occurred. The error was BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter).`
but i don't know what it means :(

Comment: The pixmap stuff can be ignored. The real problem is that "X" error, which suggests that your touchpad isn't being detected as a touchpad at all. If you go into System Settings/Mouse, do you see a "touchpad" tab, or just "mouse"? Also, what version of Ubuntu are we talking about here and what's the laptop make/model if you know it?

Comment: after the error my changes in `gpointing-device-setting` be wouldn't save !! and if i open it again, the options are unchanged !

Comment: yes, there is "touchpad" tab