# How to install Jupiter in Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander?

Tags: indicator, applet, startup-applications

I used to use "Jupiter" on previous Ubuntu versions, but now I can't find a way to install it in the newer version of Ubuntu. Is there a way to download it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter (answer is no; the bottom answer with the repository does not work wel in 13.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupiter is not supported anymore, so i would not recommend installing it on 13.10.

Source: http://jupiter.sourceforge.net/downloads.html